# How to install Chrome v59 - headless - on Ubuntu?

Tags: tools, chrome, headless, ubuntu

I wanted to check out the headless version but I am still on version 58 even after updating my system

This could dramatically reduce our test suite run time!

Comment: I find this question offtopic. It is about updating Chrome on Ubuntu. That Chrome now has a headless version does not seem to be relevant in this question. This is not a testing question as is. A better question would be: "How do I use the new headless version of Chrome?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it for me

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'

sudo apt-get update
```

[image]